# Powerline does not track git branches

Tags: 20.04, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, fish, powerline-plugin

**Stuff:**

- `WSL2:Ubuntu 20:04 LTS`
- `Bash / FishShell`
- `Powerline installed using sudo apt-get install powerline`

**Problem:**

Powerline does not changing dislpayed branch after git checkout <branch_name>. When I do git branch, git shows me that I have switched to the branch but powerline still displaying the previous one. When I disabled powerline from shell config, then branch switching is corectly displaying. I have tried with new created user and it's the same, so it's not problem with `.bashrc`/ `config.fish`. Funny thing is that in `vim`, `powerline` works correctly. Any hints what can I do and check ? Reinstall powerline does not helped ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you installed powerline only for your user, edit `./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/powerline/config_files/config.json`  and change

```
"shell": {                                                                                                                                                                                     
   "colorscheme": "default",                                                                                                                                                              
   "theme": "default",                                                                                                                                                           
   "local_themes": {                                                                                                                                                                      
      "continuation": "continuation",                                                                                                                                                
      "select": "select"                                                                                                                                                             
   }                                                                                                                                                                                      
},
```

to

```
"shell": {                                                                                                                                                                                     
   "colorscheme": "default",                                                                                                                                                              
   "theme": "default_leftonly",                                                                                                                                                           
   "local_themes": {                                                                                                                                                                      
      "continuation": "continuation",                                                                                                                                                
      "select": "select"                                                                                                                                                             
   }                                                                                                                                                                                      
},
```

Also check if the powerline daemon is running and restart it.

```
ps aux | grep powerline
powerline-daemon --replace
```

Comment: It does not help :(. I changed python version from 3.8.10 to 3.9.9 - not helped nethier. Any ideas what can I check / test ?